# Cannot install Net::SSLeay using CPAN: /bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install Net::SSLeay using CPAN. I am working on a mac and openssl is installed, it is giving me the error: /bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found. This was during a force install -- here is the entire output:

```
cpan[1]> force install Net::SSLeay

Reading '/Users/me/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 14 Nov 2020 21:29:03 GMT
Running install for module 'Net::SSLeay'
Checksum for /Users/me/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CH/CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /Users/me/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring C/CH/CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Do you want to run external tests?
These tests *will* *fail* if you do not have network connectivity. [n] y
*** Found OpenSSL-1.1.1h installed in /usr/local/opt/openssl
*** Be sure to use the same compiler and options to compile your OpenSSL, perl,
    and Net::SSLeay. Mixing and matching compilers is not supported.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lz
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Net::SSLeay
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88.tar.gz
  /Users/me/miniconda3/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for C/CH/CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88.tar.gz
cp lib/Net/SSLeay.pod blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pod
cp lib/Net/SSLeay/Handle.pm blib/lib/Net/SSLeay/Handle.pm
cp lib/Net/SSLeay.pm blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm (blib/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay)
blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm: some names are not unique when truncated to 8 characters:
 directory blib/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay:
  do_https3.al, do_https2.al, do_https4.al, do_https.al truncate to do_https
  do_httpx3.al, do_httpx2.al, do_httpx4.al truncate to do_httpx
  get_https.al, get_https3.al, get_https4.al, get_http.al, get_http3.al, get_http4.al, get_httpx.al, get_httpx3.al, get_httpx4.al truncate to get_http
  head_https.al, head_https3.al, head_https4.al, head_http.al, head_http3.al, head_http4.al, head_httpx.al, head_httpx3.al, head_httpx4.al truncate to head_htt
  post_https.al, post_https3.al, post_https4.al, post_http.al, post_http3.al, post_http4.al, post_httpx.al, post_httpx3.al, post_httpx4.al truncate to post_htt
  put_https.al, put_https3.al, put_https4.al, put_http.al, put_http3.al, put_http4.al, put_httpx.al, put_httpx3.al, put_httpx4.al truncate to put_http
  ssl_read_all.al, ssl_read_until.al, ssl_read_CRLF.al truncate to ssl_read
  ssl_write_all.al, ssl_write_CRLF.al truncate to ssl_writ
  tcp_read_all.al, tcp_read_until.al, tcp_read_CRLF.al truncate to tcp_read
  tcp_write_all.al, tcp_write_CRLF.al truncate to tcp_writ
Running Mkbootstrap for SSLeay ()
chmod 644 "SSLeay.bs"
"/Users/me/miniconda3/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- SSLeay.bs blib/arch/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.bs 644
"/Users/me/miniconda3/bin/perl" "/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/5.26.2/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/5.26.2/ExtUtils/typemap' -typemap '/Users/me/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.88-2/typemap'  SSLeay.xs > SSLeay.xsc
mv SSLeay.xsc SSLeay.c
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -c  -I"/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -no-cpp-precomp -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.88\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.88\" -fPIC --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk "-I/Users/me/miniconda3/lib/5.26.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   SSLeay.c
/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:350: SSLeay.o] Error 127
  CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88.tar.gz
  /Users/me/miniconda3/bin/make -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88.tar.gz                : make NO
```

If I could get some help installing this module it would be much appreciated. Other people have run into similar problems here, but they are always solved by installing openssl... I have already done this. Thanks.

Comment: `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found` : What version of macOS? What version of `perl`? What version of `cc` (type `cc --version`) ?

Comment: I tested this on macOS 10.15.5, perl version 5.30.1 (installed with perlbrew), `cc` version `clang-1100.0.33.17` and it compiles fine here

Comment: Also note the comment: `*** Found OpenSSL-1.1.1h installed in /usr/local/opt/openssl
*** Be sure to use the same compiler and options to compile your OpenSSL, perl,
    and Net::SSLeay. Mixing and matching compilers is not supported.`. So maybe `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang` was the compiler used when you installed openssl?

Comment: macOS 10.13.6, Perl v5.26.2, clang-700.1.81. Perhaps I need to update cc

Comment: Your `perl` was compiled with the program named `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang`, and this program is needed to build the module, but the program isn't found in your path. That's the problem. One would normally solve it by installing the package that provides `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang`. But I have no experience with Apple products

Comment: @Håkon Hægland `cc`'s version is meaningless since `cc` is not being used. `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang` is.

Comment: @ikegami Ok, anyway I tried to run `perl Makefile.PL; make` for `Net::SSLeay` and saw from `make`'s output was that it used `cc`. And when I checked `ls -l /usr/bin/cc` I saw that it was a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/clang`. So I thought that OP's `cc` could be a symlink to `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang`

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, No, the command was `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -c  -I"/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" -fno-common ...`. Not `cc`. The compiler used to build `perl` and used to build XS modules is provided by `perl -V:cc`

Answer (score 1):

You've got a wrong perl.
Your `perl -V:cc` configuration defines an invalid compiler, so you cannot compile extensions. You need a new perl, or fixup your two Config modules defining this wrong compiler.

Like as with:

sed -i 's,x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang,gcc,' `perl -V::archlib:`/Config_heavy.pl `perl -V::archlib:`/Config.pm